# SBT: How to define an includeFilter that includes all files in a certain path?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to figure out how to write an input filter that matches any file with a particular extension in a specified sub-directory. I cannot seem to get it to work.

More specifically, I want to include `modules/*.styl`

I'm having a heck of a time getting that pattern to work in my `build.sbt` file I'm trying to do something like this:

```
includeFilter in (Assets, StylusKeys.stylus) :=  "modules" * "*.styl"
```

I haven't ben able to come up with anything that even will allow SBT to start up. Anyone have a clue?

I'm using SBT 0.13.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the `includeFilter` key has type `FileFilter`. Look [this link](https://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/sxr/NameFilter.scala.html) to see how it is defined.

I think there is no easy way to do what you want since implicits from `String` to `FileFilter` produce only `NameFilter`. Those only test the file name, not the path as you want to.

You can define your own `FileFilter` based on the examples provided. The idea: you create one filter for the parent directory and then combine it with a `PatternFilter` for the file name.

```
includeFilter in (Assets, StylusKeys.stylus) := new SimpleFileFilter(file => file.getParent == "modules") && "*.styl"
```

Of course you will perhaps have to modify the function passed to `SimpleFileFilter` according to your needs.